# Load Json data with php giving an error

Tags: php, json, yql, eof

I am using this code to try to get json data from many json files using yql to compile them into one json.

My yql query is in this format:

```
select * from json where 
url="http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region_spp/recent?rtype=subnational2&r=US&sci=Dendrocygna%20autumnalis&fmt=json" 
or url = "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/geo_spp/recent?lng=-119.859512&lat=34.410240&sci=Dendrocygna%20autumnalis&dist=49&back=14&maxResults=10000&fmt=json&includeProvisional=true" 
and itemPath = "json.json"
```

I `rawurlencode` the above to obtain the `q=` part of the yql query url. Then i get this outputted url. It works fine when copy and paste the echoed url into my browser, but when i try to use `file_get_contents` on the url I get this:

```
cbfunc({"error":{"lang":"en-US","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true"},"description":"Query syntax error(s) [line 1:3675 missing EOF at '_']"}});
```

So I am asking, why does it not work when I am using it with `file_get_contents`, but does when I am using the url in my browser. Also, is there a smarter/easier way to use multiple json files together with php? I tried using curl to pull the yql json and got a weird output like:

```
8<\/howMany>34.4136<\/lat>-119.8756<\/lng>L615794
```

This method would be fine, but I don't know how to get it into a useable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use urlencode() instead of rawurlencode(). The system you're sending it to may not like the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kory! While i was adding the spaces to make my code a into a code block in the stackoverflow text editor, i realized i had a space in my json url. It works now. You indirectly helped me, so thanks!